# how to extract from jmeter using regex or jsonpath extractor

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

From the following, using regex extractor How do i extract the value of #v and "saveInto" variables preserving the line feed and CR (\r\n). I tried Json path extractor but the line feeds gets lost.

```
    "context": {
        "#t": "string",
        "#v": "jA0EAwMC.\r\n..CAqQ==\r\n"
    },
    "saveInto": [
        "jA0EAw.\r\n.JneU0=\r\n"
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like

> "#v": "(.*?)"?s},?s"save.*?[?s"(.*?)"

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the variables using JSONPath Extractor as:

1. To extract "saveInto" bit:

   ```
   $..saveInto[0]
   ```
2. To extract "#v" bit:

   ```
   $..#v[0]
   ```

Evidence:

[image: JSON Path Extractor]

As you can see, line breaks persist.

See [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) (scroll down to "Parsing JSON") for more information on using the Extractor and some form of JSONPAth language reference.